# Which setting to use in Spark to specify compression of `Output`?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-plugins

So, Spark has the file `spark-defaults.xml` for specifying what settings, including which compression codec is to used and at what stage (RDD, Shuffle). Most of the settings can be set at the application level.

### EDITED:

`conf = SparkConf()
    conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress", "true")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy")`

How can I use `spark-defaults.xml` to tell Spark to use a particular codec to compress Spark outputs only?

Option 1
`spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress             true
spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec    snappy`

Option 2:
`spark.mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress         true
spark.mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec   snappy`

Option 3:
`mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress         true
mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec   snappy`

Anyone has the proper way to sethe this (from any of these options or something similar)?  I am running Spark 1.6.1.

Answer (score 4):

You should add this to your `spark-defaults.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>snappy</value>
</property>
```

This is the same as adding these in the `spark-submit` command:

```
--conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress=true
--conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec=snappy
```

Answer (score 2):

Spark compression is explained at the following link:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization

According to this, you can configure lz4, lzf, or snappy compression as

```
spark.io.compression.codec     lz4
```

Or

```
spark.io.compression.codec     org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec
```

in the conf/spark-defaults.conf configuration file. This file is used to specify default configuration for your jobs and its executors which is going to be run on worker nodes.

Comment: Not quite what I was asking about. Edited question to provide clarity.

Comment: Every configuration can be set in SparkConf can also be set in conf/spark-defaults.conf

Comment: But what if you need to compress only output RDD, and not input nor intermediate RDDs from shuffle phase?

Comment: You can call the saveAsTextFile  function on RDD and give your compression codec as the second argument

Comment: [looking here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec):  "The wire protocol for a codec is not guaranteed compatible across versions of Spark. This is intended for use as an internal compression utility within a single Spark application."  The way I read this...  serializing to disk with one of these codecs (snappy, lz4, lzf, zstd) is a bad idea, right?  but I'm guessing using `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec` would be ok?